# Reconstructing variables from mcmc objects

Tags: r, mcmc, jags, rjags

I am using `rjags` as a sampler. The model has 3 matrices defined. The `coda.samples` function returns a list of samples. If I take the first sample list the column names look something like this:

```
> colnames(output[[1]])
"A[1,1]"  "A[2,1]"  "A[1,2]"  "A[2,2]" ... 
"B[1,1]"  "B[2,1]"  "B[3,1]"  "B[4,1]" ... 
"C[1,1]"  "C[2,1]"
```

Obviously, A, B and C are matrices in my model. I want to reconstruct them based on the mean of these samples. I can easily get the means with `colMeans(output[[1]])` but I have no idea how to easily reconstruct the matrices from this vector.

A good way for reconstruction would be the `relist()` function. So If I had matrices A, B and C in a list `L = list(A=A,B=B,C=C)` then I could transform this list to a vector with `unlist()` and convert back with `relist()`. I am looking for something similar/readymade for mcmc objects, but without avail so far - I can't believe I am the first one needing this. Obviously, `relist(colMeans(output[[1]]))` doesn't work.

Anyone can help me with reconstructing?

*Edit: note also that the `relist()` function only needs a skeleton, so extracting the skeleton from `colnames(output[[1]])` would also do the trick. Or am I complicating?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `relist()` will do the trick...

I assume your object `output` is an object of class `mcmc.list`, as defined in the R package [`coda`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/index.html), and `output[[1]]` is an object of class `mcmc` representing the sample for the first MCMC chain.

I'm pretty sure [`coda`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/index.html) does not have any understanding that e.g. `"A[1,1]"` is a JAGS matrix, it just handles it as a variable name. So you'll have to iterate over the relevant variables and impose the structure yourself.

Ideally you'd wrap this in a function like the following:

```
getMatrix <- function(output, varname, rows, cols) {
  unname(
    sapply(1:cols, function(j)
      sapply(1:rows, function(i)
        summary(output[,sprintf("%s[%s,%s]", varname, i, j)])[[1]][1]
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Thus, for example, if your matrix `B` stored in `output[[1]]` has 3 rows and 4 columns you'd write:

```
getMatrix(output[[1]], "B", 3, 4)
```

to get the means as a matrix object in R.